# How to download large Image 50 MB from server and show at iphone application with memory Management?

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I have stuck a Memory Issue about my application.
In My application I am going download 50 MB image and show into my iphone application.
Please suggest an example and proper step without Manage memory.

Comment: I hope you're kidding! Downloading such large files on a mobile device with low bandwidth is definitely the thing to avoid. You'd better process the files on the server side to get smaller images.

Comment: Sir I have some Health Report Related project. In my project we are going download xray images which store at server. These Images have very Hight Resolution, Very large size.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely should be done on the server, as suggested already.

If you have no way to do it on server side then there should be no difference between downloading small and large image.
Just download the data using `NSURLConnection` (or some another asynchronous approach), create an image from the data and set it to an image view.

I suggest displaying some sort of animation or even progress, as it may take ages to download it and convert the data to an image.
Maybe you are better to resize it to your needs after it is downloaded for better further performance.

Make sure you release all the memory right after using the objects.
In general, I think that iOS app may handle 50 MB image size...

Answer (score 0):

scale it to the size and quality it will actually be presented as (at maximum). this scaling/conversion should naturally happen on the server side.

note that the maximum presentable pixel count of ios devices is currently 3145728 (iPad 3rd Gen - Retina). using 3 bits per pixel and **no compression**, that's *less than 10 MB* for the device with the most pixels.

of course, you should **use compression** (lossy or lossless is up to you) to minimize download sizes/times. the resulting size once the file is compressed will vary depending on the complexity of the signal and the algorithms used to compress -- expect a fraction of the input.

you should also consider storing the source file at multiple sizes so a non-retina ipod or iphone (which has less memory than the 3rd gen ipad) does not need to download and process a file several times larger than the device is capable of presenting.